# Optimizing model design based on multiple relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a league leaderboard which I am trying to decide on an optimal structure to avoid problems down the line.

Currently I have three models representing the data I wish to collect. `Season`, `Challenge`, `Attempt`.

```
class Season(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()


class Challenge(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Attempt(models.Model):
    challenger = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now, I'm assuming the following statements are true in what I wish to get out of this.

1. A season runs for one year
2. A challenge runs for one month
3. A season can have many challenges
4. A challenge can have many attempts
5. A challenge cannot belong to more than one season
6. An attempt cannot belong to more than one challenge.

The difficulty I feel is going to present when I try and display the data. I would like to return a leaderboard for the current season, which calculates the best attempt for a user for each challenge and returns a query set with the user and their total points for the whole season.

*Example data*

```
Season(season='2019',
       start_date=...,  # some date object
       end_date=...,  # some date object
)

Challenge(season=1,  # represents season object above
          name='Challenge 1',
          start_date=...,  # some date object
          end_date=...,  # some date object
)

Challenge(season=1,  # represents season object above
          name='Challenge 2',
          start_date=...,  # some date object
          end_date=...  # some date object
)

Attempt(challenger=1,  # represents user object
        challenge=1,  # represents challenge 1 above
        points=5
)

Attempt(challenger=2,  # represents user object
        challenge=1,  # represents challenge 1 above
        points=10
)

Attempt(challenger=1,  # represents user object
        challenge=2,  # represents challenge 2 above
        points=5
)


Attempt(challenger=2,  # represents user object
        challenge=2,  # represents challenge 2 above
        points=10
)
```

*Expected result*

1. Challenger 2 - 20 points
2. Challenger 1 - 10 points

How can I make this model better represent the results I need. I've looked at a through relationship but I'm not sure if I understand it fully or if it's needed here.

Also how would I then get the results I am looking for using the ORM

Comment: 3, 4, 5, 6 is ready. 1 and 2 just populate with data.

Comment: I'm aware these models reflect my assumptions, my question is that even though the current design reflects this I feel it's suboptimal for allowing me to get the result I wish.

Comment: I just do not understand what is Challenger 2 - 20 points ?

Comment: It is the results I am wanting to be returned based on the data in the objects above.

Comment: Good schema will be generated, exactly what you want (IMHO).

Comment: I can't quite get to the results I'm needing from this schema, hence why I'm asking the question.

Comment: What kinf of unexpected result you got ?

Comment: I can't get an aggregated list of each challenger and their total points for that season.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is good, don't change it.  For the result you want, try something like this:

```
Attempt.objects.filter(challenge__season__season='2019').values('challenger__name').annotate(total_points=Sum('points')).order_by('-total_points')
```

This takes all attempts, filters them down to just season with name '2019', then grabs all the challenger names and then aggregates them by the sum of the challengers' attempt points (which seems to be what you want, but you can use Max as well instead of Sum).

One issue with this approach (which, btw, I have to credit to this source: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html ) is that if multiple challengers have the same name, they will be grouped together, something you probably don't want.  So you may want to group by challenger 'pk' and 'name' instead.

Comment: And if you want the full model objects rather than just values, you can play with .group_by('challenger_pk') instead of using .values(...)